# Are there security concerns / issues with passing role claims via PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider in Blazor .net 8?

Tags: authentication, blazor, roles

I have a .net 8 blazor app using the "new" project style. I'm using static SSR as well as WASM.

By default, the PersistingRevalidationAuthenticationStateProvider and PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider only sync userId and email claims. I've added a small amount into this as a proof of concept sort of thing, but it was non sensitive data (getting users real name).

I've reached the point where I am adding roles, however. I have a page which renders some additional content when the logged in user has the Admin role (using AuthorizeView).

When the page loads initially, this is visible (to the correct user) due to it rendering through static SSR. When it gets passed over to WASM however, the role claim is missing and the content disappears.

I could sync the role claims across using the Auth state providers above, and I have just implemented that... however I'm unsure if this is a wise idea or if I might be creating some possible security issues.

If there are security concerns in doing this, Can you help me to understand why, and what the real solution should be?

Here is my implementation, to be verbose:

Serializing authentication state on server:

```cs
internal sealed class PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider : RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory;
    private readonly PersistentComponentState state;
    private readonly IdentityOptions options;

    private readonly PersistingComponentStateSubscription subscription;

    private Task<AuthenticationState>? authenticationStateTask;

    public PersistingRevalidatingAuthenticationStateProvider(
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory,
        PersistentComponentState persistentComponentState,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(loggerFactory)
    {
        scopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        state = persistentComponentState;
        options = optionsAccessor.Value;

        AuthenticationStateChanged += OnAuthenticationStateChanged;
        subscription = state.RegisterOnPersisting(OnPersistingAsync, RenderMode.InteractiveWebAssembly);
    }

    protected override TimeSpan RevalidationInterval => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

    protected override async Task<bool> ValidateAuthenticationStateAsync(
        AuthenticationState authenticationState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Get the user manager from a new scope to ensure it fetches fresh data
        await using var scope = scopeFactory.CreateAsyncScope();
        var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        return await ValidateSecurityStampAsync(userManager, authenticationState.User);
    }

    private async Task<bool> ValidateSecurityStampAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(principal);
        if (user is null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (!userManager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            var principalStamp = principal.FindFirstValue(options.ClaimsIdentity.SecurityStampClaimType);
            var userStamp = await userManager.GetSecurityStampAsync(user);
            return principalStamp == userStamp;
        }
    }

    private void OnAuthenticationStateChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> task)
    {
        authenticationStateTask = task;
    }

    private async Task OnPersistingAsync()
    {
        if (authenticationStateTask is null)
        {
            throw new UnreachableException($"Authentication state not set in {nameof(OnPersistingAsync)}().");
        }

        var authenticationState = await authenticationStateTask;
        var principal = authenticationState.User;

        if (principal.Identity?.IsAuthenticated == true)
        {
            var userId = principal.FindFirst(options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType)?.Value;
            var email = principal.FindFirst(options.ClaimsIdentity.EmailClaimType)?.Value;
            var name = principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
            var roles = principal.FindAll(ClaimTypes.Role).Select(x => x.Value);

            if (userId is not null && email is not null && name is not null)
            {
                state.PersistAsJson(nameof(UserInfo), new UserInfo
                {
                    UserId = userId,
                    Email = email,
                    Name = name,
                    Roles = roles
                });
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        subscription.Dispose();
        AuthenticationStateChanged -= OnAuthenticationStateChanged;
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

And then receiving said Auth state on the client:

```cs
internal class PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private static readonly Task<AuthenticationState> defaultUnauthenticatedTask =
        Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity())));

    private readonly Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask = defaultUnauthenticatedTask;

    public PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider(PersistentComponentState state)
    {
        if (!state.TryTakeFromJson<UserInfo>(nameof(UserInfo), out var userInfo) || userInfo is null)
        {
            return;
        }

        List<Claim> claims = [
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userInfo.UserId),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userInfo.Name),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, userInfo.Email)];

        if(userInfo.Roles is not null)
        {
            claims.AddRange(userInfo.Roles.Select(x => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, x)));
        }

        authenticationStateTask = Task.FromResult(
            new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims,
                authenticationType: nameof(PersistentAuthenticationStateProvider)))));
    }

    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync() => authenticationStateTask;
}
```

Comment: Nothing in the client is safe. Passing role claims is fine. All data sent back to the server should be checked for Authentication and Authorization maintaining the server as the point of truth. I use claims in the client to enable/disable/hide UI functionality.

Comment: Cheers for that. That was essentially what I wanted to do - show / hide an admin link (for example) based on whether the role was present. Page for the admin link has its own [Authorize] tag requiring Admin role, so navigating there wouldn't expose anything etc... I just worried that passing a cookie back with a role claim as a part of it could cause an issue somewhere else along the line...